# CIL data types and equivalent of them in C#

Tags: c#, .net, cil

CIL has some instructions such as `ldc.r8 <float64 (num)>, ldc.r4 <float32 (num)>, ldc.i8 <int64 (num)>, ldc.i4.s <int8 (num)>` that are load constants into the stack.

Well, what are the equivalent for these data types (`int32, int64, float32, float64`) in C#?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
C# type     CIL type    .NET Framework type
============================================
short       int16       System.Int16
int         int32       System.Int32
long        int64       System.Int64

float       float32     System.Single
double      float64     System.Double
```

See also [the data type summary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ya5y69ds.aspx).